# Tkinter - running Clock class in mainloop asynchronously with multiple pages

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tkinter

I'm building a GUI using tkinter with multiple pages. I want to run the `Clock` class asynchronously. Here is the sample image:

[image: code_output]

To test whether the `Clock` is running asynchronously I include `time.sleep(5)` in the `show_frames()` and it fails as it sleeps together with the `shows_frames()`.

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time1 = ''
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%A %d,%m,%Y %H:%M:%S')
        self.mFrame = tk.Frame()
        self.mFrame.pack()

        self.watch = tk.Label(self.mFrame, text=self.time2, font=('Times_New_Roman', 20))
        self.watch.pack()
        
        self.changeLabel()
        
        
    def changeLabel(self):
        
        self.time2 = time.strftime('Date: %A %d/%m/%Y Time: %H:%M:%S')
        self.watch.configure(text=self.time2)
        
        if threading.Thread.is_alive:
            threading.Thread(target=self.change_async).start()

    def change_async(self):
        self.changeLabel()
        time.sleep(1)


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        window = tk.Frame()
        window.pack()
        
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Page1, Page2, Page3):
            frame = F(window,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frames(Page1)
        Clock()

    def show_frames(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.title(page.__name__)
        time.sleep(5)

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page one", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Next", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20),
                command = lambda: controller.show_frames(Page2)).pack()
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page two", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Next", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20),
                command = lambda: controller.show_frames(Page3)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Prev", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20),
                command = lambda: controller.show_frames(Page1)).pack()
class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page three", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Prev", font=('Times_New_Roman', 20),
                command = lambda: controller.show_frames(Page2)).pack()

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you have `time.sleep` in `show_frames`? that will freeze the GUI so obviously it won't update with the current time even tho the other thread works without interruption, also why do you start so many threads? you call a method in the thread which then creates another thread, just use one thread and a `while True:`, also don't put `tkinter` code in other threads, if you want to update GUI with data from other threads, use queues and `after` "loops"

Comment: This will launch an infinite cascade of threads.  Remember that you cannot update your GUI from any thread except the main thread.  You need to use `app.after` to request a callback after a period of time.  And, as Matiss pointed out, you cannot use `time.sleep` in a GUI thread.  You must think "event-driven programming", not linear programming.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I exaggerated.  But the key issue is that you cannot call `self.watch.configure` from a thread.  It has to be done from the main thread.